# Extract real part of a complex expression better than Re does

Tags: symbolic, trigonometry

I have a complex expression with real positive variables only.

Mathematica Input Style:

```
PP = -((α (γ Cosh[y1 α] + α Sinh[y1 α])(-γ Cosh[(-L +  y2) α] + α Sinh[(-L + y2) α]))
    /(s (2 α γ Cosh[L α] + (α^2 + γ^2) Sinh[L α]))) /. α -> Sqrt[s/d] /. 
    γ -> (kd + s)/ka /. s -> -ω*I
```

which leads to

$
PP=-\frac{i \sqrt{-\frac{i \omega }{d}} \left(\frac{(\text{kd}-i \omega ) \text{Cosh}\left[\text{y1} \sqrt{-\frac{i \omega }{d}}\right]}{\text{ka}}+\sqrt{-\frac{i \omega }{d}} \text{Sinh}\left[\text{y1} \sqrt{-\frac{i \omega }{d}}\right]\right) \left(-\frac{(\text{kd}-i \omega ) \text{Cosh}\left[(-L+\text{y2}) \sqrt{-\frac{i \omega }{d}}\right]}{\text{ka}}+\sqrt{-\frac{i \omega }{d}} \text{Sinh}\left[(-L+\text{y2}) \sqrt{-\frac{i \omega }{d}}\right]\right)}{\omega  \left(\frac{2 (\text{kd}-i \omega ) \sqrt{-\frac{i \omega }{d}} \text{Cosh}\left[L \sqrt{-\frac{i \omega }{d}}\right]}{\text{ka}}+\left(\frac{(\text{kd}-i \omega )^2}{\text{ka}^2}-\frac{i \omega }{d}\right) \text{Sinh}\left[L \sqrt{-\frac{i \omega }{d}}\right]\right)}
$

Now I want to extract the real part of this by assuming real only variables and then
`Re[PP]`. Mathematica 8 can't extract it.

I saw on different forums that many people have had difficulties with extracting real or imaginary parts of expressions with built-in `Re`.

Some propose to replace `Re` by `ComplexExpand[ ( PP + Conjugate[PP] )/2 ]`, which seems to work well in some cases. Do you have other suggestions?

All the variables are real and positive, so that I define at the beginning of my Mathematica notebook:

```
$Assumptions = ω > 0 && d > 0 && L > 0 && y1 > 0 && y2 > 0 && 
    y1 < y2 && ka > 0 && kd > 0 && s > 0 && y1 < L && y2 < L
```

My version of Mathematica is `$Version = "8.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 10, 2011)"`

Comment: Could you post an example where `ComplexExpand` does not work well ?

Comment: ComplexExpand[Re[PP]] will work. If you want Conjugate in the answer use ComplexExpand[Re[PP], TargetFunctions -> {Conjugate}]. Whatever you do, you will get a very long and complicated expression. Using Re alone is never going to "work" (well, it actually does "work", but does not expand - a different matter) except when dealing with numbers - how could it? The answers depends on which symbols are real and which are not.

Comment: `ComplexExpand[Re[PP]]` does return a result.  The output is ugly because the result also depends on the sign of variables.

Comment: Can we assume {d>0,ka>0,kd>0,L>0,y1>0,y2>0,\\[Omega]>0}  ?

Comment: Every variable is real and >0. I just edited my original post accordingly.

Comment: ComplexExpand[Re[PP]] refined with positive "restrictions" works well. It is indeed ugly but that's not mathematica's "fault". Thank you very much to all of you. Could you explain the reason why ComplexExpand[Re[PP]] is working better than Assuming[Re[PP], _everything positive_] ?

Comment: @MaximilienLevesque because by default, `Re` simply does not perform expansion/simplification.

Comment: Actually the answers are equivalent but you seem to be using an older version of Mathematica (?) The way to get a simpler answer is to avoid expanding Cosh and Sinh since they are already real.

Comment: @AndrzejKozlowski **Thanks** anyway for you answer and not letting me trying around your input for days. Maybe you could put something as an answer about ComplexExpand[Re[PP]] so that I can give you a thumb up ? (and then delete this comment)... or whatever is required by stackexchange's quality standards?

Comment: See also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9340/complex-number-operations-telling-mathematica-variables-are-real) for more about taking complex conjugates when variables can be assumed to be real.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Removing the imaginary portion of an `expression` is done by doing

```
ComplexExpand[Re[expression]].
```

Using just [`Re`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Re.html) alone will not work as `Re` does no evaluation on symbols with unknown complex parts.

Now as stated in the problem and the comments above this particular problem requires a fair amount of assumptions. The simplest way to add local assumptions is to use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assuming.html). But this will not work, so we must instead make use of [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html). For example:

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand[Re[expression]], a > 0]
```

where `a` is a symbol used in `expression` and is a [real](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reals.html) number greater than zero.

Comment: Indeed, the expression is _too_ large for _Mathematica 8_ to output everything, but I am not sure that is related to the real part extraction. thanks anyway for this clear answer.

Comment: This part about Assuming is completely wrong. Assuming has no effect on ComplexExpand. You will need to add Simplify, FullSimplify or Refine. Assuming alone does nothing when applied to functions that do not accept Assumptions.

Comment: It is also untrue that Re does no evaluation. Try for example Re[Pi + I E]. Obviously it can't do any evaluation if an expression contains symbols about which it is not known if they have non-zero imaginary parts.

Comment: Oops, in that case feel free to improve the answer. It is a community wiki thing, I don't get any rep or credit from it. I simply attempted to summarize the comments with the purported answers. :) I'll get to correcting it myself soon otherwise.

Comment: Can we use the same command if we have a matrix instead of an expression?