# Complex number operations: telling Mathematica variables are real

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, complex, assumptions

I want to do `Conjugate[a + b*I]`, but when I do that, the solution is 
`Conjugate[a] - I*Conjugate[b]`; when for me, a and b are reals.

I want to obtain the following expresion : `a-b*I`

The same problem exists with the function `Abs`.

Comment: Related: [Extract real part of a complex expression better than Re does](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3306/121)

Comment: Related: [Does the Im function work with symbolic arguments?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/does-the-im-function-work-with-symbolic-arguments)

Comment: Related: [How to tell Mathematica that certain variables are real/imaginary, integer-valued, etc](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66273/5478)

Comment: Related: [How to assume **all** variables in my code are reals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118955/5478)

Answer (score 21):

```
Conjugate[a + b*I]//ComplexExpand
```

or

```
Refine[Conjugate[a + b*I], {a, b} \[Element] Reals]
```

Comment: Note that the first method will tend to convert exponentials to trig functions, which can cause very undesirable behavior if you have many exponentials (e.g., multiplying Gaussians together).  The second method generally works well, but can arguably be improved by using `_Symbol ∈ Reals` as the assumption instead of `{a, b} ∈ Reals` since the former allows the method to be bundled into a function for re-use without passing the list of variables manually.  See my [alternate answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156648/1806).

Comment: `Refine` doesn't seem to be recognized by Wolfram Alfa - any suggestions on how to defines variables as Real there?  Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

The **most complete and extendable answer** is to define

```
Conj[x_] := Refine[Conjugate[x], _Symbol ∈ Reals];
```

Then we get

```
Conj[a + I b]
```

> a - i b

as expected.  It is also possible to generalize so that `Conj` takes a second argument telling it which variables to treat as complex, recovering similar abilities of `ComplexExpand`

```
Conj[x_, exclu_:{}] := 
          Refine[Conjugate[x], _?((Head[#] == Symbol && ! MemberQ[exclu, #]) &) ∈ Reals];
Conj[a + I b, {b}]
```

> a - i Conjugate[b]

**EDIT**: [Cheng Tao found an example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9340/complex-number-operations-telling-mathematica-variables-are-real/156648?noredirect=1#comment697087_156648) with undesired behavior:

```
Conj[a Exp[I b] + c Exp[I d]]
```

> Conjugate[a $e^{i b}$ + c $e^{i d}$]

This seems to be an issue with `Conjugate` not automatically distributing over addition.  I have a patch to fix this behavior, but I suspect there is still an underlying pathology:

```
ConjNew[x_] := Refine[
    Conjugate[x] //. {Conjugate[sum_Plus] :> Conjugate /@ sum}, 
   _Symbol ∈ Reals];
ConjNew[a Exp[I b] + c Exp[I d]]
```

> a $e^{-i b}$ + c $e^{-i d}$

(I could not find a way to use `Distribute` to fix this. Note also the [issues with using Plus in a pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241305/1806).)

#### Issues with other methods

This question and related versions have been asked many times before: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23738/how-to-take-conjugate-of-a-function),[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66273/how-to-tell-mathematica-that-certain-variables-are-real-imaginary-integer-value),[3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/does-the-im-function-work-with-symbolic-arguments/4974#4974),[4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9340/complex-number-operations-telling-mathematica-variables-are-real),[5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77543/complex-conjugate),[6](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113169/how-to-take-complex-conjugate-of-a-real-variable),[7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15961/a-problem-about-simplifing-conjugate),[8](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/remove-annoying-conjugate),[9](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104939/is-there-a-simple-way-to-get-the-conjugate-of-a-complex-term-provided-all-infor),[10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118955/how-to-assume-all-variables-in-my-code-are-reals),[11](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/extract-real-part-of-a-complex-expression-better-than-re-does).  Here's a round up.

The basic issue is that using `Conjugate` alone doesn't work because Mathematica doesn't know your variables are real:

```
Conjugate[a + I b]
```

> Conjugate[a] - i Conjugate[b]

[Rojo's suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9341/1806) to deploy `ComplexExpand` is [very](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103267/1806) [common](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15963/1806) [advice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23740/1806) and it works in the simplest case

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[a + I b]]
```

> a - i b

but it has the undesirable behavior of converting some exponentials functions to trig functions.

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Exp[a + I b]]]
```

> $e^a$ Cos[b] - i $e^a$ Sin[b]

This becomes terrible when you have multiple exponentials. (**Edit**: Interestingly, you can *occasionally* prevent `ComplexExpand` from converting `Exp`'s to `Cos`'s and `Sin`'s using the option `TargetFunctions -> Conjugate`.  This does't help with `a E^(I b)`, but it does help with `a E^(I b)+c E^(I d)`. Note that `TargetFunctions -> Exp` is not an allowed option.)

One can use `Refine` and assume everything is real

```
Refine[Conjugate[a + I b], _ ∈ Reals]
```

> a - i b

but then you can [run into trouble](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118956/1806) when it starts assuming *every* expressions is real (not just variables):

```
Refine[Conjugate[Sqrt[I*a]], _ ∈ Reals]
```

> $\sqrt{i a}$

Like [Rojo's alternate answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9341/1806), you can assume that only the symbols in your expression are real

```
Refine[Conjugate[a + I b, {a,b} ∈ Reals}]
```

> Conjugate[$\sqrt{i a}$]

but this becomes quite unwieldy if you have many variables or if you make variable substitutions.  (If you forget one variable in a large expression, you may not notice.)  Furthermore, if you want to encapsulate this by defining a function like `Conj`, you need to pass the list of variables manually or scrape them from the input expression.

Avoiding this issue by making the reality assumption for all things with the `Head` of `Symbol` gives the answer above.

Also note that you can use `Simplify` in place of refine, but this will muck around by simplifying your expression,

```
Simplify[Conjugate[I(x^2 + 2 x y + y^2)], _Symbol ∈ Reals]
```

> -i $($x - y$)^2$

when you may really have wanted `-I(x^2 + 2 x y + y^2)`.

The simple hack of flipping the sign on `i` is too fragile to rely on.  This works

```
(a + I b) /. {I -> -I}
```

> a - i b

but this doesn't

```
Exp[-I] /. {I -> -I}
```

> $e^{-i}$

because

```
FullForm[Exp[-I]]
```

> Power[E,Complex[0,-1]]

Even if you try the rule `{Complex[re_, im_] :> Complex[re, -im]}`, there are [issues with complex-valued functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23738/how-to-take-conjugate-of-a-function#comment188925_67686) like `ArcSin[2]`.

Comment: This method does not seem to be working on `Conj[t1 Exp[I k1] + t1 Exp[I k2]]` ?

Comment: Good find.  This seems to be an issue with `Conjugate` not automatically distributing over addition. (I'd have hoped that `Refine` would fix this, but it doesn't.) I hacked together a patch in the answer above (see the edit).  I'd welcome a better understanding of this issue.

Answer (score 3):

And for the absolute value of `z` use `Norm` command instead of `Abs`:

```
Refine[Norm[a + b*I], {a, b} ∈ Reals]
```

Comment: Or: `norm[z_] := Sqrt[ComplexExpand[z Conjugate[z]]]` and then just `norm[a + b I]`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Simplify` and `Assumptions`

`Simplify[Conjugate[a + I*b], Assumptions -> {{a, b} \[Element] Reals}]`

Result

a - I b

[image]