# a problem about simplifing conjugate

Tags: simplifying-expressions

the situation is as follows

```
σ[i_] := PauliMatrix[i];
m := Sum[a[i]*σ[i], {i, 1, 3}]
$Assumptions = Element[{q, w, e, o}, Reals];
a[1] := q;
a[2] := w;
a[3] := e - o;
```

what I want is the `Conjugate` of the eigenvectors, so

```
Conjugate[Eigenvectors[m]]
```

and this gives

```
{{-((-Conjugate[e] + 
Conjugate[o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2 e o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2]])/(
Conjugate[q] - I Conjugate[w])), 
1}, {-(-Conjugate[e] + Conjugate[o] - 
  Conjugate[Sqrt[e^2 - 2 e o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2]])/(Conjugate[q] - 
  I Conjugate[w]), 1}}
```

now simplify, gives

```
{{(e - Conjugate[o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2 e o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2]])/(q - I w), 
1}, {(e - o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2 e o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2])/(q - I w), 1}}
```

and here comes the problem, in the second eigenvector, the "conjugate" is totally gone, and this is right. because I have assumed all the variables are real. While in the first eigenvector, there is still one "conjugate" in the expression, But this Conjugate should be simplified too without any problem.

If you copy the `Conjugate` part and simplify, it does simplify.

```
Simplify[Conjugate[o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2 e o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2]]]
```

and gives

```
o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2 e o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2]
```

So why Mathematica's simplify just don't take a further step in  simplifying first eigenvector as it did in simplifying second eigenvector?? This kind of asymmetry confused me.

So is it a bug or something? Did I missed some step in the simplify procedure?

---

**Edit**
It seems that few people are interested in my question. But I do really frequently encounter such annoying simplifying problem. So I choose another example extracted from my real calculation. And expecting more suggestions.

first, a little prelude

```
$Assumptions=Element[{x,y},Reals]
Simplify[Conjugate[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]]
```

result

```
Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
```

This trivial example illustrates that "simplify" is smart enough to deal with Conjugate and it can recognize whether the expression in the Conjugate is real or not. But I encounter an expression which is essentially the same thing only with more variables than the above trivial example. Mathematica's simplify function failed to do it correctly.

with the global assumptions

```
$Assumptions = Element[{t1, t2, kx, ky, Δ, ϕ}, Reals]

Simplify[Conjugate[Sqrt[
t1^2 (2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Cos[ky/2] + Cos[ky])^2 + 
4 t1^2 (Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] - Cos[ky/2])^2 Sin[ky/
2]^2 + (Δ + 4 t2 Cos[(3 ky)/2] Sin[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Sin[ϕ] - 
2 t2 Sin[Sqrt[3] kx] Sin[\[Phi]])^2]]]
```

the result will still have `Conjugate` intact. And it shouldn't be like this. It should be smart enough to recognize that the expression under the sqrt is absolutely greater than or equal to zero and throw out the `Conjugate`.

Rojo mentioned "MapAll" , But "MapAll" can do nothing more in this situation.

And Nasser M. Abbasi proposed to `ComplexExpand`. Yes, `ComplexExpand` can tackle this expression. But let me point out the difficulty encountered in real case.

In real case, there will be very large expression(even several pages long). And directly `ComplexExpand` such large expression will cost considerable cpu time (I have tried), because it will transform many expression into Re and Im form which I do not expect. So the most efficient way is still simplify directly first. But as I have showed, there will be several "Conjugate" so obstinate and these Conjugate hides in such long expressions which are difficult to find. I have to find them term by term and `ComplexExpand` them to test if they are really real. And this is so inconvenient!

I hope some one helps me out.

Comment: See also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9340/complex-number-operations-telling-mathematica-variables-are-real) for more about taking complex conjugates when variables can be assumed to be real.

Comment: @JessRiedel Thank you so much

Answer (score 7):

When I wrote

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Simplify[-Conjugate[o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2 e o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2]] -Conjugate[e]]
(* -e - Conjugate[o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2*e*o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2]] *)
```

then simply removed the minus sign

```
Simplify[Conjugate[o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2 e o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2]] - Conjugate[e]]
(*-e + o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2*e*o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2]*)
```

This told me I need to `ComplexExpand` . And no need for assumptions. Put back the minus sign, and now I get what you expected to see

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand[-Conjugate[o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2*e*o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2]]-Conjugate[e]]]
(* -e-o-Sqrt[e^2-2 e o+o^2+q^2+w^2] *)
```

so use `ComplexExpand`

Now your example can be written as

```
Clear["Global`*"]
σ[i_] := PauliMatrix[i];
m := Sum[a[i]*σ[i], {i, 1, 3}];
a[1] := q;
a[2] := w;
a[3] := e - o;
sol = Conjugate[Eigenvectors[m]];
Simplify[ComplexExpand[sol]]
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It can't be a bug since the result is not wrong. It simply isn't as simplified as you would have wished, and that is very often the case.

This time, `Simplify` doesn't seem to be trying enough transformations. Try with `FullSimplify`

```
Conjugate[Eigenvectors[m]] // FullSimplify
```

> {{-((-e + o + Sqrt[(e - o)^2 + q^2 + w^2])/(q - I w)), 1}, {(
>         e - o + Sqrt[(e - o)^2 + q^2 + w^2])/(q - I w), 1}}

`Simplify` clearly knows to remove that `Conjugate`. But, for some reason, it doesn't reach deep enough in your expresion, or try hard enough, to make this simplification.

Given this, another alternative to fix it is to make sure `Simplify` reaches way down your expression, using `MapAll`

```
Simplify //@ Conjugate[Eigenvectors[m]]
```

> {{-((-e + o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2 e o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2])/(q - I w)), 1}, {(
>     e - o + Sqrt[e^2 - 2 e o + o^2 + q^2 + w^2])/(q - I w), 1}}

Comment: By the way, I don't have a clear idea of how much time the `MapAll` solution takes for a big expression, but it probably wastes a lot too. If your assumptions are those, you probably should go with `ComplexExpand` with a simple `Simplify` afterwards