# Is there a simple way to get the Conjugate of a complex term, provided all information is available?

Tags: complex

I've found a few threads addressing this, but they all seem to have pretty clunky answers, and it's hard to believe there's not a more elegant solution in Mathematica:

[Remove annoying Conjugate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/remove-annoying-conjugate)

[a problem about simplifing conjugate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15961/a-problem-about-simplifing-conjugate)

The first thread is very clunky and I'm having trouble implementing it in a standalone function, and the 2nd solution isn't working for me, as far as I can tell.

Here's the simplest I can reduce my problem to. Let's say I have a term:

```
bop = Sqrt[x-2]
```

And I want to find the complex conjugate (CC) of it, and let's assume x is Real. I think MMa runs into problems because, depending on the value of x, the form of the CC will be pretty different. For example, if x>2, then bop is real, and the CC is just bop.

On the other hand, if x<2, then the value in the Sqrt is negative, you'd have to pull an imaginary i out of the Sqrt, and flip its sign.

Alright, so now I'm giving it all the information it should need to give me the unambiguous answer:

```
Assuming[x \[Element] Reals && x < 2, FullSimplify@Conjugate@bop]
```

Yet, this still gives me:

```
Conjugate[Sqrt[-2 + x]]
```

I'm sure I'm just missing something, but what is it? Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

edit: Alright, I solved my contrived example, by doing this:

```
Assuming[x \[Element] Reals && x < 2, 
 Simplify@Conjugate@ComplexExpand@bop]

-I Sqrt[2 - x]
```

Which is good. The Simplify[] step is actually kind of vital because without it, it's comes out as a mess, even for something that simple.

Here is my actual application, which is still doing something funky. I have this term of a matrix:

```
t22 = 0.5 (0. + 
    0.5 E^((0. + 5.14215 I) Sqrt[-2 + energy]) (1 - Sqrt[-2 + energy]/
       Sqrt[energy])) (1 - Sqrt[energy]/Sqrt[-2 + energy]) + 
 0.5 (0. + 
    0.5 E^((0. - 5.14215 I) Sqrt[-2 + energy]) (1 + Sqrt[-2 + energy]/
       Sqrt[energy])) (1 + Sqrt[energy]/Sqrt[-2 + energy])
```

Which is very ugly, unfortunately. The important things to notice are, first, it is complex, and second, there are 3 regimes of interest: energy <= 0, 0 < energy <= 2, and energy >=2.

I don't mind taking care of those three cases separately, so let's look at the simpler case of energy >= 2.

My goal is to find $|t_{22}|^2=t_{22}^*t_{22}$, which should then be a real number.

The first hurdle is getting $t_{22}^*$. Using Refine doesn't work:

```
Refine[Conjugate[t22], energy > 2]
```

gives

```
Conjugate[
 0.5 (0. + 
     0.5 E^((0. + 5.14215 I) Sqrt[-2 + energy]) (1 - 
        Sqrt[(-2 + energy)/energy])) (1 - Sqrt[
     energy/(-2 + energy)]) + 
  0.5 (0. + 
     0.5 E^((0. - 5.14215 I) Sqrt[-2 + energy]) (1 + 
        Sqrt[(-2 + energy)/energy])) (1 + Sqrt[energy/(-2 + energy)])]
```

However, it works if I stick a Simplify in there (I kind of thought that's what Refine was doing though?):

```
t22conj=Refine[Simplify@Conjugate[t22], energy > 2]
```

gives:

```
(E^((0. + 5.14215 I) Sqrt[-2 + energy]) (-0.5 + 0.5 energy + 
   0.5 Sqrt[(-2 + energy) energy] + 
   E^((0. - 10.2843 I) Sqrt[-2 + energy]) (0.5 - 0.5 energy + 
      0.5 Sqrt[(-2 + energy) energy])))/Sqrt[(-2 + energy) energy]
```

Alright, now I want to find $|t_{22}|^2$. Just trying it simply leaves imaginary parts in the answer:

```
T = Refine[(t22conj*t22), energy > 2]

1/Sqrt[(-2+energy) energy] E^((0. +5.14215 I) Sqrt[-2+energy]) (0.5 (0. +0.5 E^((0. +5.14215 I) Sqrt[-2+energy]) (1-Sqrt[(-2+energy)/energy])) (1-Sqrt[energy/(-2+energy)])+0.5 (0. +0.5 E^((0. -5.14215 I) Sqrt[-2+energy]) (1+Sqrt[(-2+energy)/energy])) (1+Sqrt[energy/(-2+energy)])) (-0.5+0.5 energy+0.5 Sqrt[(-2+energy) energy]+E^((0. -10.2843 I) Sqrt[-2+energy]) (0.5 -0.5 energy+0.5 Sqrt[(-2+energy) energy]))
```

If I evaluate this at an actual value in the assumed range, the imaginary part is indeed small:

```
T /. energy -> 2.6 

1.3564 - 1.11022*10^-16 I
```

However, I'd really like a general form where I don't have to plug in a value and then take the real part (because it should already be only real). I assume this has to do with numerical precision, and that in *theory* something times its conjugate is real, but here, if you're even slightly off, an imaginary part will remain.

Is there any way to make this work?

thank you!

Comment: `Simplify[Conjugate[Sqrt[x - 2]], x >= 2]` works.

Comment: @march, I assume you were highlighting the alternate case? I'll edit my post to reflect that, but my question is regarding when x<2, where it's doing something I don't expect.

Comment: Or I wasn't reading carefully enough. :/

Comment: `FullSimplify[Conjugate[t22] t22, energy > 2]` works okay

Comment: @SimonWoods, awesome, it does! Now I have one more annoying question... why does it not work (i.e., leave in obvious Conjugate[]'s) if I do the same thing, but for energy<2 && energy>0 together? Even a Refine after that with the same assumptions doesn't simplify it. Thank you!

Comment: @YungHummmma Note that `FullSimplify[Conjugate[t22] t22, energy < 0]` also works, so you have two of the three ranges covered already. One question: do you have to have approximate numerical values in your expression, or could you do the calculations symbolically first and then plug in numbers later?

Comment: @MarcoB, actually, I realized that I won't have to look at the energy < 0 case. I could absolutely have just the symbols in there and plug the numbers in later, I just assumed it would be easier for MMa if it had raw numbers at this step.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: the answer below refers to a somewhat different version of the OP's question.

---

[`Refine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html) seems to be your friend here:

```
bop = Sqrt[x - 2];
Refine[Conjugate@bop, x < 2]

(* Out: -I Sqrt[2 - x] *)
```

Notice that, by implicating $x$ in an inequality, the system automatically includes the assumption that it must therefore be real, so only the inequality condition is necessary.

---

This is one more case that highlights that **the user's and the system's concepts of "simpler" may not coincide** (see also the discussion in [my answer to Advice for Mathematica as Mathematician's Aid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92686/27951)).

`Simplify` and its friends try to minimize the complexity of an expression, as measured mostly (but not uniquely) by the [`LeafCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html) of the expression. It so happens that in your case the `LeafCount` of your desired form is *higher* than that of the original `Conjugate` expression:

```
LeafCount[-I Sqrt[2 - x]]             (* Out: 13 *)
LeafCount[Conjugate[Sqrt[-2 + x]]]    (* Out:  8 *)
```

You can make sense of this somewhat unexpected result by looking at the `FullForm` of these expressions:

```
FullForm[-I Sqrt[2 - x]]
(* Out: Times[Complex[0, -1], Power[Plus[2, Times[-1, x]], Rational[1, 2]]] *)

FullForm[Conjugate[Sqrt[-2 + x]]]
(* Out: Conjugate[Power[Plus[-2, x], Rational[1, 2]]] *)
```

So, *even though `Refine` is explicitly attempted by `Simplify`* (as stated in the details of the documentation to `Refine`), its result is discarded in this case because the system deems it "more complex", and Simplify returns the unmodified input as the best form it can come up with!

Comment: Thanks, this is great. What is Refine doing that Simplify doesn't? It's bizarre to me that I have to use ComplexExpand.

Comment: @YungHummmma That is an excellent question. I think that it actually has to do with how the system measures expression complexity, rather than with any special `Refine` magic; I have updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting. I always enjoy seeing how the machinery of MMa works. I've updated my post to reflect my actual application, where refine isn't working... I'd appreciate any feedback, thank you.