# Remove annoying Conjugate

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Here is an expression

```
Conjugate[1/Sqrt[
1 + (-2 + es + Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + 
Sqrt[(-2 + es + Cos[kx] + Cos[ky])^2 + Sin[kx]^2 + Sin[ky]^2])^2/(
Sin[kx]^2 + Sin[ky]^2)]]
```

With the assumptions that `es`, `kx`, `ky` are real variables, I want to remove the head `Conjugate` in a safe manner with `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`. But unfortunately, Both `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` failed to do this seemingly simple job even you use `MapAll`.

Most of the time, `ComplexExpand` can remove `Conjugate`. But not in this expression. `ComplexExpand` will yield

[image: ComplexExpand result]

The reason that I insist on removing `Conjugate` is that I have to differentiate this kind of expression. With `Conjugate` in an expression, I will get results containing derivatives of `Conjugate`.

So how do I remove `Conjugate` other than removing it manually?

(Note that in my actual work, such `Conjugate` expressions are embedded in a much larger expression and I do not know in advance whether the expression `Conjugate` heads is real or not until I take a careful look at it.)

#### Edit

rcollyer mentioned `Refine`, but both Jens and I found it to be inefficient. But this inspired me to investigate the function `Refine`, and this aroused more confusion.

According to *Mathematica*'s documentation (the following sentences were extracted directly from the entry on `Refine`):

> `Refine` gives the **form of *expr* that would be obtained if symbols in it were replaced by explicit numerical expressions** satisfying the assumptions *assum*.  `Refine` must have assumptions and performs only those **basic simplifications which would be automatic for numeric inputs**.`Refine` is one of the transformations tried by Simplify

So I came up with several questions: How does `Refine` refine expr? Will it really try to plug several sets of possible numerical values which are satisfied by the assumptions and see what comes out after **the automatic simplification**? But if so, how could `Refine` be certain it had tried enough sets of values? If it was not like this, then what does *Mathematica*'s documentation mean?

I've tried several examples which are very confusing (**es,kx,ky are all declared real variables in `$Assumptions`**):

1.

```
In:=Refine[Conjugate[Sqrt[Sin[kx]^2 + (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2]]]
out=Sqrt[(Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2 + Sin[kx]^2]
```

`Conjugate` is gone.

2.

```
In:=Refine[Conjugate[Sqrt[Sin[kx]^2 + Sin[ky]^2 + (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2]]]
Out=Conjugate[Sqrt[(Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2 + Sin[kx]^2 + Sin[ky]^2]]
```

Add one more term under the `Sqrt` and `Conjugate` remains.

3.

```
In:=Refine[Conjugate[Sqrt[Sin[kx]^2 + Cos[ky]^2 + (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2]]]
Out=Sqrt[Cos[ky]^2 + (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2 + Sin[kx]^2]
```

Change the added term from `Sin` to `Cos`, `Conjugate` is gone again.

Although the above three examples completely confused me, I add one more.

```
In:=Refine[Conjugate[Sqrt[Tan[es]^2]]]
Out=Conjugate[Sqrt[Tan[es]^2]]
```

According mathematica's documentation on  `ComplexExpand`:

> `ComplexExpand` expands *expr* assuming that all variables are real. `ComplexExpand` automatically threads over lists in *expr*

So now I let `ComplexExpand` do the same job:

```
In:=ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[Sin[kx]^2 + (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2]]]
Out=Sqrt[(Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2 + Sin[kx]^2]

In:=ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[Sin[kx]^2 + Sin[ky]^2 + (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2]]]
Out=Sqrt[(Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2 + Sin[kx]^2 + Sin[ky]^2]

In:=ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[Sin[kx]^2 + Cos[ky]^2 + (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2]]]
Out=Sqrt[Cos[ky]^2 + (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Sin[es])^2 + Sin[kx]^2]
```

All of the `Conjugate`s are gone.

So `ComplexExpand` recognized that all of the three arguments are real and `Refine` failed, even though they both used the same assumptions. Also, `Refine` did not fail consistently; it succeeded on two of the examples. This proves `Refine` should have the same abilities as `ComplexExpand`, at least in the above cases.

So how does one explain the mysterious failure of `Refine` in the second example? What's more, `ComplexExpand` too has its failures. I really hope somebody could perfectly **explain the simplification procedure applied by *Mathematica***. Help me clear out all the clouds from my head.

Comment: I just wrote an answer without seeing your last edit, but I was thinking about just that problem of having other complex parts. So maybe you can actually use what I wrote - unless someone else finds a fully automatic remedy...

Comment: Given your additional information your questions turns from remove `Conjugate` to test whether the argument is real and then remove `Conjugate`. Is that right?

Comment: yes, you're right. And if the argument is not real, the `Conjugate` still has to be simplified.

Comment: Sorry if I seem to be thick here (it's probably because I am). If you remove the `Conjugate` regardless of whether the argument is real or complex why differentiate between the two cases?

Comment: Yes, that's right. My purpose is of course to remove the `Conjugate` regardless of whether the argument is real or complex, because I have one more step to differentiate it. But now you see mathematica even can not remove `Conjugate` when argument is real, will you expect that it will do better with the complex argument case? It will be a fool when encounter `Sqrt` as Jens has said so.

Comment: My apologies, I somehow dropped the outer `Sqrt`, and you are correct, it doesn't work with it present.

Comment: @user15964. To understand what "thread" means in "ComplexExpand automatically threads over lists in expr", look up `Thread` in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html?q=Thread&lang=en)

Comment: That's a compelling list of comparisons, and I wouldn't know how to explain them all (have encountered them in similar guise before, but usually looked for alternative ways of avoiding `Conjugate` in the first place).

Answer (score 12):

It's true that `Conjugate` can be annoying, but it's understandable that you're having difficulty removing it in an automated way. The culprit are the square roots, which are actually harmless but aren't recognized by *Mathematica* to be harmless.

So if you don't want to manually remove `Conjugate` but also don't want to waste time rewriting the expression to rearrange the square roots (which may or may not be possible), then you could interfere manually at the level of the square roots instead. This isn't really any better than manually removing `Conjugate` in your case, but it could be useful if you *do* have places where `Conjugate` can't be removed, but you still want to assume that square roots are real:

```
Clear[fakeSqrt]

fakeSqrt /: Conjugate[fakeSqrt[arg_]] := fakeSqrt[arg]

Conjugate[
  Sqrt[1 + (-2 + es + Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + 
         Sqrt[(-2 + es + Cos[kx] + Cos[ky])^2 + Sin[kx]^2 + 
           Sin[ky]^2])^2/(Sin[kx]^2 + Sin[ky]^2)] /. 
   Sqrt[arg_] :>  fakeSqrt[arg]] /. fakeSqrt[arg_] :> Sqrt[arg]
```

> $\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sqrt{(\text{es}+\cos
>    (\text{kx})+\cos (\text{ky})-2)^2+\sin
>    ^2(\text{kx})+\sin
>    ^2(\text{ky})}+\text{es}+\cos (\text{kx})+\cos
>    (\text{ky})-2\right)^2}{\sin
>    ^2(\text{kx})+\sin ^2(\text{ky})}+1}$

Here I temporarily replace the `Sqrt` heads by `fakeSqrt` which has been defined to be its own complex conjugate independently of the argument. At that point `Conjugate` sees what we want it to see, and right after that we can undo the replacement. As I said above, this is still manual interference, but it attacks a little closer to the root of the problem.

Comment: It is actually interesting that Mathematica does not realise that the Sqrt are harmless. In fact, it can simplify the expression when removing the -2 and having the assumptions Im[es]==Im[kx]==Im[ky]==0.

Comment: I've added more stuff in my original post. Would you please help me take a look at it, OK?

Comment: Wow, I have a pun at the end of this answer that I didn't notice at first...

Answer (score 6):

The expression is in general complex even with all variables real since if the argument of any [`Sqrt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sqrt.html) is negative the `Sqrt` will be complex.

```
expr = Conjugate[
   1/Sqrt[1 + (-2 + es + Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + 
          Sqrt[(-2 + es + Cos[kx] + Cos[ky])^2 + Sin[kx]^2 + 
            Sin[ky]^2])^2/(Sin[kx]^2 + Sin[ky]^2)]];
```

Since the issue is ultimately just the need to differentiate the expression, specify [`TargetFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html) for [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
expr = ComplexExpand[expr, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Simplify;
```

Although quite complicated, the derivatives are readily available, e.g.,

```
{exprDes, exprDkx, exprDky} = D[expr, {{es, kx, ky}}]
```

Simplifying the expressions is quite slow.