# Simplifying complex expresion (without ComplexExpand or User defined rules)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Many times, I've struggled with simplifying complex expressions, such as this extraordinarily simple expression, and Mathematica wont do it:

```
$Assumptions = {l>0,a>0,a \[Element]Reals, l \[Element]Reals}
Conjugate[(Exp[I a])^(2 l)] //FullSimplify
```

Where Mathematica returns the same thing with no simplification.
I told it the assumptions which make it very obvious to just change the sign of the exponent, and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I looked [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/112487), but it seems like they have to define their own rules to do this kind of thing. I'm also [saw here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/remove-annoying-conjugate) that you can do `//ComplexExpand //FullSimplify` for this expression, but it doesn't seem to work in all cases. Why should it be nessecary and why doesn't FullSimplify do it already? Also, I think ComplexExpand assumes that all variables are real, which was the case in this expression, but isn't always the case. So how would I do it then?

Comment: what do you want `Conjugate[(Exp[I a])^(2 l)]`  simplified to?  (and it is really not good idea to use `l` for variable, it looks like `1`. Better use `n` or `m` or something other letter.

Comment: It is inconsistent to say that Mathematica won't simplify a complex expression while simultaneously not making use of one of its primary tools for simplifying complex expression, i.e., `ComplexExpand`. While `ComplexExpand` defaults to assuming that all variables are real, the optional second argument is used to specify which variables are complex. `FullSimplify` doesn't do everything because it would be inefficient to unnecessarily use additional tools in cases where they would have little value. Also, the "preferred" form is often a matter of opinion.

Comment: We can't also use user defined rules? i.e. no replacement is allowed? This is too much restriction. it is like saying one has to add 2 numbers but not allowed to use the plus sign.

Comment: "`ComplexExpand` assumes that all variables are real, which was the case in this expression, but isn't always the case" - indeed, so if you have things in your expression that aren't supposed to be real, that's what you use the *second argument* of `ComplexExpand[]` for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP seeks already existing functionality (namely, the second argument of `ComplexExpand`), but refuses to use it as implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming they want `Conjugate[Exp[I a]^(2 n)]` to become `(Exp[I a]^(-2 n)`  ?

By using a rule (De Moivre’s formula) (I do not see how it is possible otherwise)

```
ClearAll[a, n, r, m];
expr = Exp[I a]^(2 n);
e1 = ExpToTrig[expr] /. r_. (Cos[a_] + I Sin[a_])^(m_.) :> r^m (Cos[m a] + I Sin[m a]);
FullSimplify@Conjugate[e1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `ComplexExpand` (just to compare with)

```
expr = Exp[I a]^(2 n);
FullSimplify@ComplexExpand@Conjugate@expr
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If this is not is meant by the question, will delete this answer.