# What is the value Re[Sqrt[1+I*2*x]]?

Tags: complex

When I try to evaluate `Re[Sqrt[z]]`, for some values of *Mathematica* fails to evaluate it.

For example,

```
Re[Sqrt[2 + I*x]]`
```

> `Re[Sqrt[2 + I x]]`

How can I get the real number in `Sqrt[complex number]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex number operations: telling Mathematica variables are real](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9340/complex-number-operations-telling-mathematica-variables-are-real)

Comment: Concerning those voting for the duplicate: could you indicate how that would produce the solution $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\left(x/2\right)^2}}$?  (I had to manually derive this.)

Comment: It may be of interest that, in V9, the predictive UI, after returning `Re[Sqrt[2 + I*x]]` unevaluated, suggests 'ComplexExpand`. If you accept the suggestion, _Mathematica_ then returns `(4 + x^2)^(1/4) Cos[1/2 Arg[2 + I x]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try playing with this:

```
ComplexExpand[Re[Sqrt[y + I x]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
```

> (x^2 + y^2)^(1/4) Cos[1/2 ArcTan[y, x]]

```
ComplexExpand[Re[Sqrt[2 + I 5]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] //TrigToExp //FullSimplify
```

> Sqrt[1/2 (2 + Sqrt[29])]

The function `ComplexExpand` is quite intelligent. For example, you can have mixed variables - ones that you know are real and those that may be complex. Here how it can derive a nice formula:

```
ComplexExpand[Re[Sqrt[(2 + I x)/a]], a, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] //
    TrigToExp // FullSimplify // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Given that there is a universal algebraic solution, we should not be satisfied with trigonometric expressions.**

The simplest, most direct way I have found to obtain the real part of the root of $x + i y$ begins with the *inverse* of the square root, suggesting we would like the $u$ part of this solution:

```
Solve[(u + I v)^2 - (x + I y), {u, v}, Reals] (* Does not succeed *)
```

Unfortunately *Mathematica* complains about the presence of imaginary values when real solutions are sought.  So we have to force a separation into real and imaginary parts:

```
u /. #& /@ Solve[ComplexExpand@Through[And[Re[#]==0&, Im[#]==0&][(u+I v)^2-(x+I y)]], {u, v}]
```

We get four solutions, of which two are evidently imaginary, leaving

$$u = \pm\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

as the two real solutions, as expected. (You could specify `Reals` as an argument to `Solve`, which will return just the two real solutions--but in the form of `Root` objects.  They take some further manipulation to put into this nice form.)

This technique generalizes in an obvious way to more complicated inverse functions than mere square roots.

Comment: +1 - why mathematica can't do this more simply has baffled me before.