# How to take conjugate of a function?

Tags: complex, special-functions, assumptions

Naïvely this is what happens and it obviously is not helpful!

```
In[7]:= Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, θ, ϕ]]
Out[7]= -(1/2) E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Sqrt[3/(2 π)] Conjugate[Sin[θ]]
```

So, I tried stating initially that $\theta$ and $\phi$ are reals but still that doesn't seem to have helped any bit,

```
In[8]:= θ ∈ Reals; ϕ ∈ Reals;

In[9]:= SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, θ, ϕ]
Out[9]= -(1/2) E^(I ϕ) Sqrt[3/(2 π)] Sin[θ]

In[10]:= Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, θ, ϕ]]
Out[10]= -(1/2) E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Sqrt[3/(2 π)] Conjugate[Sin[θ]]
```

Kindly tell me how to do this? (I want to calculate sums like $\sum\limits_{m=-\ell}^{\ell}\left| Y_{l,m} (\theta,\phi)\right|^2$.)

Comment: Try `Simplify[Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, θ, ϕ]], θ ∈ Reals && ϕ ∈ Reals]`

Comment: Simply writing θ ∈ Reals; ϕ ∈ Reals; is not the way to indicate to Mathematica that those variables are real. Try looking up `$Assumptions` and `Assumptions`.

Answer (score 4):

Almost always in such situations, `ComplexExpand` is your friend:

```
Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, θ, ϕ]] // ComplexExpand
(* -(Sqrt[3/(2*Pi)]*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ])/2 + (I/2)*Sqrt[3/(2*Pi)]*Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ] *)
```

Comment: Thanks! But isn't there a way to just make Mathematica understand that theta and phi are reals? I mean, I want to do many calculations like this in one file and I would like to have it declared once and for all that \theta and \phi are reals. Isn't there a way for that?

Comment: This thing of "ComplexExpand" doesn't seem to work if I say have a coefficient like of $(1/a)Y_{l,m}(\theta,\phi)$. Then `ComplexExpand` doesn't understand that $a$ is real and is making an unnecessary mess of the expression.

Comment: `ComplexExpand` does an expansion making the assumption that all variables and symbolic constants involved are real. There are not really "assertions" like `\[theta] \[Element] Reals` that do anything. Sometimes setting values for the global `$Assumptions` will do what you want, but that's only for affecting subsequent uses of certain functions such as `Simplify` and `Integrate`.

Comment: I disagree with this answer, though not to the extent of downvoting. `ComplexExpand` does more, than just assuming all symbols to be real. As you can see, It has transformed `Exp[I \[Phi]]` to `Cos[\[Phi]] + I Sin[\[Phi]]`. I view this as undesirable behavior and would often prefer to see it drop `Conjugate`s, with minimal alteration of the form of the expression.

Comment: I agree with LLIAMnYP.  Here is a minimal method that avoid this issue: `Refine[Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, θ, ϕ]], _Symbol ∈ Reals]`.  For an exhaustive discussion, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156648/1806).

Answer (score 3):

This is the spherical harmonic:

```
SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, \[Theta], \[Phi]]
```

It returns this:

```
-(1/2) E^(I \[Phi]) Sqrt[3/(2 \[Pi])] Sin[\[Theta]]
```

And this is its complex conjugate:

```
SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, \[Theta], \[Phi]] /. I -> -I
```

returning this:

```
-(1/2) E^(-I \[Phi]) Sqrt[3/(2 \[Pi])] Sin[\[Theta]]
```

as it can be expected.

Answer (score 3):

Rule

```
{Complex[re_, im_] :> Complex[re, -im]}
```

seems to convert complex expressions which contain symbols which are meant to be real.

Rule

```
{I -> -I}
```

does not, even on simple example:

```
2 I /.{I -> -I}
```

> ```
> 2 I
> ```

the reason being that symbol `I` is automatically translated by *Mathematica* to

```
Complex[0, 1]
```

and rule above is interpreted by *Mathematica* as

```
Complex[0, 1] -> Complex[0, -1]
```

However, when I apply it to a simple expression (say, 2 + 3 I), I am working with a different expression (in this case `Complex[2, 3]`), so the rule is not applicable.

Comment: Your pattern is not exhaustive. For example `ArcSin[2]` is a complex number that won't get picked up by your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The best way about this, using again the spherical harmonics, is this:

1. Define a symbol for the complex conjugate, e.g. `Ybar`
2. Simplify the expression for the spherical harmonic:

   ```
   Y[l_, m_, θ_, ϕ_] := SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ]
   ```
3. Define `Ybar`

   ```
   Ybar[l_, m_, θ_, ϕ_] := SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ] /. I -> -I
   ```

And that's it