# How to tell Mathematica that certain variables are real/imaginary, integer-valued, etc

Tags: functions, complex, assumptions, variable-definitions

I'm trying to expedite some quantum mechanical calculations (expectation values etc.) by running them through *Mathematica*. When I say, for example,

```
u[x_] := Sqrt[2/L] * Sin[Pi * n * x / L]
```

and then take the complex conjugate, I get

```
Sqrt[2] Conjugate[Sqrt[1/L]] Sin[(π Conjugate[n x])/Conjugate[L]]
```

But I want to tell *Mathematica* that some of the parameters are real (i.e. $L$) and some are integer valued and real (i.e. $n$). Is there a way to do that? I've tried adapting some syntax that I've seen in other context (but do not strictly know what it means or does) but it hasn't worked. For example,

```
Conjugate[u[x], Im[n] = 0]
Sin[n*Pi] /. n = Integer
```

Don't work the way I want them to. Chugging through this, however, when it comes time to compute values (like, in this example, $\langle p^2\rangle$, I get the following:

```
Integrate[u[x]*(-h^2)*u''[x], {x, 0, L}]
(* => (h^2 n π (n π - 1/2 Sin[2 n π]))/L^2 *)
```

where the second term there is clearly zero for all integer values of $n$ (but *Mathematica* doesn't know that).

Comment: `But I want to tell Mathematica that some of the parameters are real (ie L) and some are integer valued` you can us e `ComplexExpand` it says `expands expr assuming that all variables are real`, for integers, you can use `Assuming[Element[x,Integers],Simplify[....]]`

Comment: There's no general way to declare a variable as real, integer etc.  Instead, some functions take an `Assumptions` option which affects that function.  Take a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingAssumptions.html and also `ComplexExpand`.  There can be a default for the `Assumptions` option through `$Assumptions` but it won't affect everything, only functions that know about assumptions.

Answer (score 38):

You can also  use `Refine` with `Element` :

```
Refine[Sqrt[2] Conjugate[Sqrt[1/L]] Sin[(Pi* Conjugate[n x])/Conjugate[L]],
{Element[L, Reals], Element[n, Integers]}]
```

gives

[image]

and if you add that `L>0`:

```
Refine[Sqrt[2] Conjugate[Sqrt[1/L]] Sin[(Pi* Conjugate[n x])/Conjugate[L]],
{Element[L, Reals], Element[n, Integers], L > 0}]
```

[image]

Other simple examples :

**1.** Example with reals

```
Re[x + I*y]
```

returns

```
-Im[y] + Re[x]
```

but if x is assumed to be real :

```
Refine[Re[x + I*y], Element[x, Reals]]
```

gives

```
x - Im[y]
```

and if x and y are assumed to be reals :

```
Refine[Re[x + I*y], {Element[x, Reals], Element[y, Reals]}]
```

gives

```
x
```

**2.** Example with integers

```
Sin[n*Pi]
```

gives the same

```
Sin[n*Pi]
```

but if `n` is assumed to be an integer :

```
Refine[Sin[n*Pi], Element[n, Integers]]
```

returns

```
0
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I wanted. Can I tell mathematica that a variable is "globally" real valued, etc? Or do I have to add that Element[] function to every new input line?

Comment: After playing around with Refine[] for a bit, it looks like I can just do all of my calculations within the Refine function, add it my constraints at the end, and get a nice looking answer. Am I correct in that assessment?

Comment: @MatthewBrunetti Theoretically yes ... It is maybe safer to use assumptions as soon as possible in your calculations. As was shown in the other answer, for example `Integrate` can use Assumptions. It depends on the problem. Anyway see the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AssumptionsAndDomains.html) in particular the tutorials under "Learning Ressources" ;)

Comment: @MatthewBrunetti Maybe the function [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) is what you are looking for because it "spreads" the assumptions to all the functions in an expression at the same time.

Comment: This doesn't work `Refine[Im[E^(t + I Pi/4)], Element[t, Reals]]` :(

Comment: @SantoshLinkha Try first `TrigFactor[E^(t + I Pi/4)]` or `ComplexExpand[E^(t + I Pi/4)]` :)

Comment: Note that, in place of the assumption `Element[t, Reals]` you can use the assumption `_Symbol ∈ Reals` to assume that *all* explicit variables are real.  This allows you to encapsulate this in a function without having to manually pass a list of arguments. For an exhaustive discussion, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156648/1806).

Answer (score 18):

```
$Assumptions = n > 0 && n ∈ Integers && L ∈ Reals && L > 0
```

You can type `∈` symbol in the form `n ∈ Integers` using <kbd>ESC</kbd>+el+<kbd>ESC</kbd>, or by typing `\[Element]`, or you can use the the alternative `Element[n, Integers]` form.

To delete all global assumptions: `$Assumptions = True`

Comment: According to the documentation, use `[Esc (Escape) key] el [Esc key]`.

Answer (score 7):

`Conjugate` by default assumes that all symbolic quantities are potentially complex. This may seem annoying at first, but there is a very good reason for it, and one way to see why is to define your own version of `Conjugate`, and see it fail. For educational purposes, I do that below.

Define `$Conjugate` as follows:

```
$Conjugate[x_] := x /. Complex[a_, b_] :> a - I b;
```

This simply replaces any occurrence of `I` with `-I`. For example:

```
$Conjugate[u[x]]
```

produces

```
Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1/L] Sin[(n π x)/L]
```

which is presumably what you expected.

Beware that this simple definition of `$Conjugate` is only guaranteed to work on numbers and functions which satisfy $f(\overline{x})=\overline{f(x)}$, which oddly enough is true for the majority of analytic elementary functions, such as `Zeta`, `Gamma`, `Sin`, `Log`, and many others.

One possible counterexample is `SphericalHarmonicY`:

```
$Conjugate[ SphericalHarmonicY[3, θ, ϕ, a + b I]] /. 
                                                    {θ -> 2.3, ϕ -> 1.0, a -> 1.2, b -> 2.5}
$Conjugate[ SphericalHarmonicY[3, θ, ϕ,  a + b I] /. 
                                                    {θ -> 2.3, ϕ -> 1.0, a -> 1.2, b -> 2.5}]
```

which produces two different outputs:

```
-104.193 + 41.8086 I
-0.00105549 - 0.000423525 I
```

In contrast, replacing `$Conjugate` with the built-in `Conjugate` gives correct results. So while `Conjugate` may give silly-looking outputs, it is guaranteed to be correct; thus a simple substitution $a+bi\rightarrow a-bi$ does not necessarily give correct results!

Meanwhile, to make the assumption that `n` is an integer in your integral, do this:

```
Simplify[Integrate[u[x]*(-h^2)*u''[x], {x, 0, L}], Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
```

which returns

```
(h^2 n^2 π^2)/L^2
```

Comment: "which oddly enough is true for the majority of analytic elementary functions" -- This is true for an analytic function iff it has real coefficients in its Taylor series (as can easily be seen by expanding it in said Taylor series). Thus in particular if the function is real on [a segment of] the real axis, and analytic it will work. Be careful with functions with singularities, however. Your statement about logarithms is not in general true. Notice that on Mathematica's branch $\log(-1) = i \pi$ but $\log(\overline{-1}) = i \pi \neq \overline{i\pi}$. You need to cross branches.

Comment: "$Conjugate[x_] := x /. Complex[a_, b_] :> a - I b;"  is Great for simple cases.