# Assumption that a parameter is real

Tags: assumptions

I'm making some calculations, where I use the command Conjugate[f[x]]. In the function f[x] appears a parameter J, which is Real. How can say mathematica that it should not take the Conjugate of J?

So, I would like to say mathematica that J is real. I tried to write

Assumptions -> J e Reals

in the beginning of the code, but it doesnt work.

Ideas?

Best

Comment: If you really want to set the assumption globally for the session, then look up `$Assumptions` in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66273/how-to-tell-mathematica-that-certain-variables-are-real-imaginary-integer-value)

Try

```
    Refine[Conjugate[f[x]], J \[Element] Reals]
```