# Making the assumption that variables are real

Tags: assumptions

I have a problem with using `Assumption`. The question arises when I try generating `matrix` with rolling code:

```
vect = {α, 1 - α, 0, 0, d, -Id };
prod0 = {vect};
prod1 = Transpose[prod0];
Assumptions -> {α > 0, α ∈ Integers, d > 0, d ∈ Integers};
matrix = prod1.Conjugate[prod0];
```

but the result is:

[image]

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66273/how-to-tell-mathematica-that-certain-variables-are-real-imaginary-integer-value)

Comment: Look at [$Assumptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) and [Assuming](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another.

```
vect = {α, 1 - α, 0, 0, d, -I d};
prod0 = {vect};
prod1 = Transpose[prod0];
matrix = prod1.Conjugate[prod0];

Refine[matrix, Assumptions -> {α > 0, α ∈ Integers, d > 0, d ∈ Integers}]
```

> ```
>  {{α^2, (1 - α) α, 0, 0, d α, I d α}, 
>   {(1 - α) α, (1 - α)^2, 0, 0, d (1 - α), I d (1 - α)}, 
>   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>   {0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0}, 
>   {d α, d (1 - α), 0, 0, d^2, I d^2}, 
>   {-I d α, -I d (1 - α), 0, 0, -I d^2, d^2}}
> ```

Note that I wrote `I d` and not `Id` as you did in your question. Also, note that an option such as

```
 Assumptions -> {α > 0, α ∈ Integers, d > 0, d ∈ Integers}
```

can not be asserted globally at top level, but must be given as an option to those functions which are programmed to accept that option.

Answer (score 3):

here's one way:

```
vect = {α, 1 - α, 0, 0, d, -I d};
prod0 = {vect};
prod1 = Transpose[prod0];
assum = {α > 0, α ∈ Integers, d > 0, d ∈ Integers};
matrix = FullSimplify[prod1.Conjugate[prod0], assum]
```