# Why do I get "Re" function when it is clear which is the real part?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions, complex

Mathematica keeps giving me the "Re" function in an evaluation, even though my parameter assumptions should be enough to deduce the real part:

Here is the latex result:

[image]

As you can see, I keep getting the Real function in the exponential, but I do not know how to get rid of it... My assumptions should make it clear which one is the imaginary part, since I give as assumtpions that all parameters are real...

Here is the code:

```
z[y_] := (B^2 + 1)^(1/4) + B/(B^2 + 1) kx;
F[n_] := Integrate[Exp[-z[y]^2]*HermiteH[n, z[y]]*Exp[-(y - y0)^2/(4 σ^2) + I k0y*y],
          {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> σ > 0 && kx ∈ Reals && 
              B ∈ Reals && k0y ∈ Reals && y0 ∈ Reals];

Simplify[Abs[F[1]]^2]
```

> 16 E^(-2 Re[
>          Sqrt[1 + B^2] + (2 B kx)/(1 + B^2)^(3/4) + (B^2 kx^2)/(1 + B^2)^2 -
>            Ik0y (y0 + σ^2 Ik0y)]) π Abs[(((1 + B^2)^(1/4) + 
>            B^2 (1 + B^2)^(1/4) + B kx) σ)/(1 + B^2)]^2

I guess my question is: **How can I get rid of the Re function**? Future computations will become much lengthier so I want to be able to short it now.

Comment: This happens because Mathematica assumes all variables are complex unless you tell it otherwise. See, e.g.,  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66273/43522

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Assumptions` with the final `Simplify`.

```
z[y_] = (B^2 + 1)^(1/4) + B/(B^2 + 1) kx;
F[n_] = Integrate[Exp[-z[y]^2]*HermiteH[n, z[y]]* Exp[-(y - y0)^2/(4 σ^2) + I k0y*y]
                 , {y, -Infinity, Infinity}];

Simplify[Abs[F[1]]^2,
          Assumptions -> σ > 0 && kx ∈ Reals && B ∈ Reals&& k0y ∈ Reals && y0 ∈ Reals]
```

> $16 \pi  \sigma ^2 \left(\frac{B \text{kx}}{B^2+1}+\sqrt[4]{B^2+1}\right)^2 \exp \left(-2
>    \left(\frac{B^2 \text{kx}^2}{\left(B^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{2 B
>    \text{kx}}{\left(B^2+1\right)^{3/4}}+\sqrt{B^2+1}+\text{k0y}^2 \sigma ^2\right)\right)$

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. I just started using Mathematica so I falsely assumed that the assumptions given to the integral would propagate.

Comment: you will learn the tricks in time ;). On a quick note, if  `∈ Reals` fails to work, try `>0`.

Comment: note you can set `$Assumptions` , which will get passed to anything having the `Assumptions` option.