# how can I define a symbol as a global real number?

Tags: complex, variable-definitions

Say there is a complex number `a=x+I`, where `x` is a real number. Then `b=Join[{a},{1+I}]`, and I use `Re[b]`.

The result is `{Re[x],1}`, but the desired result is `{x,1}`.

How can I set `x` as a global real number from the very beginning? Please be noted that `x` should be treated a real number no matter what kind of calculation is used.

I have read many questions, but none is fit to my situation.

This problem bothers me for a very long time, and I hope someone can give me the answer.

Comment: look for [$Assumptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) . The first example shows how to set global assumptions. `$Assumptions = a > 0`.

Comment: Related: [(66273)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66273/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Assumptions = x \[Element] Reals

a = x + I
b = Join[{a}, {1 + I}]
Refine[Re[b]]
```

> i+x
>
> {I + x, 1 + I}
>
> {x, 1}

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
ComplexExpand[Re[b], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
(*{x, 1}*)
```

is what you're looking for!

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I need set 'x' as a global real number. And I have many calculation afterwards. Your answer is local.

Comment: @Robin_Lyn You have to realize, though, that only functions that take an `Assumptions` option will be aware of global assumptions. Ulrich's approach, on the other hand, is explicit and local, which is actually a *good thing* so you don't fall into hard-to-debug situations that depend on remote assumptions / assignments.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for your advice. Now I know both the global and local definition for a variable. Many thanks again for Ulrich Neumann

Comment: If you `Set` `x` to be a specific real number, it'll be that number, but there is no way in general to force *Mathematica* to treat a free symbol as representing a real number in all circumstances.