# Complex conjugate

Tags: matrix, complex

How do I complex conjugate a vector?

```
E^(-((I β)/2)) p (Cos[α/2] (Cos[θ]^2 + Sin[θ]^2 Sin[ϕ] (-I Cos[ϕ] + Sin[ϕ]))
+ E^(I β)Sin[α/2] (Cos[θ]^2 + Sin[θ]^2 Sin[ϕ] (I Cos[ϕ] + Sin[ϕ])))
```

I tried doing `Assuming[β ∈ Reals, c[[1]]^*`, but that didn't work :\ ...
I just want i's flipped, but I'm getting this:

[image]

---

Attempt at using ComplexExpand as suggested my LLiaMnYP. Still doesn't look as compact as `c[[1]]` if I just change all the i's by hand :(

[image]

Comment: You are getting this as there is no way for Mathematica to know, that all other variables are real. Check out the documentation for `ComplexExpand` IIRC.

Comment: tried it... see pic above... naturally, Mathematica decided to expand exponentials and rearrange everything %\ and cc* product has changed to a really long string compared to what it was when I just changed i's manually

Comment: Is `p` a factor or a function?

Comment: p is a factor here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
expr = E^(-((I β)/2)) p (Cos[α/2] (Cos[θ]^2 + Sin[θ]^2 Sin[ϕ] (-I Cos[ϕ] + Sin[ϕ])) + 
    E^(I β) Sin[α/2] (Cos[θ]^2 + Sin[θ]^2 Sin[ϕ] (I Cos[ϕ] + Sin[ϕ])))
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr /. Complex[x_, y_] :> Complex[x, -y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: YES! Thank you!
Tho it also returned "Complex::argr: Complex called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected." for some reason.

Comment: @Solarmew please try it now.

Comment: Perfect :] Thanks so much!

Comment: Cool trick. This does literally "flip the i's", as OP requested. Just be warned, if you have `I` represented as `Sqrt[-1]` anywhere, this will probably not work.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP you are not supposed to use Sqrt[-1] for I in Mathematica :) but I just checked and M converts Sqrt[-1] to Complex[0,1] so it is ok.

Comment: Agreed, I was too lazy to extend to more elaborate constructs such as `Sqrt[-a]` (where `a` may be positive, but not have a value assigned to it and remain in symbolic form) and a large class of functions, although elementary, but for which the relation `Conjufate[f[x]]==f[Conjugate[x]]` does not hold. Of course, OP's expression does happen to be one of those where you just need to flip the `I`s, I just wanted to point out, that your trick may not work in some cases even if all variables are real.

Comment: Following up on LLIAMnYP's comment, here is a more general method for taking the conjugate assuming all the symbols are real: `Refine[Conjugate[expr], _Symbol ∈ Reals]`.  For an exhaustive discussion, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156648/1806).

Answer (score 4):

You might use:

```
  FullSimplify@ComplexExpand@Conjugate[(* expression *)]
```

in your case, it returns:

$$
e^{\frac{i \beta }{2}} p \left(\sin \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) e^{-i (\beta -\phi )} \left(\cos ^2(\theta ) \cos (\phi )-i \sin (\phi )\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) \left(\cos ^2(\theta )+\sin ^2(\theta ) \sin (\phi ) (\sin (\phi )+i \cos (\phi ))\right)\right)
$$

Comment: Mine still returned the same expression as in the first picture, but without Conjugate[ ] around beta.
(how did you input such pretty text so fast?)
I also typed {beta, p, alpha, theta, phi} instead of just beta. That got p outside of Conjugate[ ] but left all the trig functions in.
Tried including trig function, but that also didn't do anything.

Comment: @Solarmew such "pretty text" is input using $\LaTeX$. See a [basic help page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) and an [extended tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about what MathJax supports.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do

```
Refine[Conjugate@c[[1]],
       Assumptions->(\[Alpha] | \[Beta] | \[Phi]) \[Element] Reals]
```

This also works in cases when you have additional manifestly complex variables in your expression (`ComplexExpand` assumes that all variables are real). Of course in that case you would not add those in your Assumptions. For example:

```
Refine[Conjugate[a b], Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]
(*
==> a Conjugate[b]
*)
```