# how to take complex conjugate of a real variable

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have a function defined as follows:

```
g[θ_] := 1/k (Exp[-I δ0] Sin[δ0] + 3 Exp[I δ1] Sin[δ1 Cos[θ] + 
            5/2 Exp[I δ2 (3 (Cos[θ])^2 - 1))
```

and I compute the product of `g` with its complex conjugate as follows:

```
f[θ] Conjugate[f[θ]]
```

which gives me:

```
4.18986*10^-30 ((0.453154 - 0.288691 I) + (0.443562 - 0.0670825 I) Conjugate[Cos[θ]] + 
 (2.49994 - 0.0174532 I) (-1 + 3 Conjugate[Cos[θ]]^2)) ((0.453154 + 0.288691 I) + 
  (0.443562 + 0.0670825 I) Cos[θ] + (2.49994 + 0.0174532 I) (-1 + 3 Cos[θ]^2))
```

However I want theta to be real so that `Conjugate[Cos[θ]]` is just `Cos[θ]` and likewise for `Conjugate[Cos[θ]]^2`.

How can I do this?

*EDIT*

I should say my end goal is to plot and integrate the product of `g` with its product. I've tried what Rashid Zia suggested like so:

```
Plot[
 Simplify[g[θ] Conjugate[g[θ]], θ ∈ Reals], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 AxesLabel -> {rad, m^2/sr}
]
```

but the plot doesn't look like what I'm told it should, and the integral:

```
Integrate[2 Pi Simplify[g[θ] Conjugate[g[θ]], θ ∈ Reals], {θ, 0, Pi}]
```

doesn't seem to return the expected value.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: The parentheses and brackets are not balanced in the definition of `g[θ]`. Please correct the definition. Also, `f[θ] Conjugate[f[θ]]` should read `g[θ] Conjugate[g[θ]]`

Comment: If all the parameters are real, just use `ComplexExpand`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Simplify with the assumption that θ is an element of the Reals.

```
f = Conjugate[Cos[θ]]
Simplify[f, θ ∈ Reals]
```

Comment: Note that using things like `Simplify` may perform manipulations you do not want, like replacing `x^2 + 2 x y + y^2` with `(x+y)^2`.  The minimal method is to use `Refine` as so: `Refine[Conjugate[a+I b], θ ∈ Reals]`.  Also, in place of the assumption `θ ∈ Reals` you can use the assumption `_Symbol ∈ Reals` to assume that *all* explicit variables are real.  This allows you to encapsulate this in a function without having to manually pass a list of arguments. For an exhaustive discussion, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156648/1806).

Comment: Thanks @JessRiedel. I appreciate the suggestions and great linked discussion.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is numerical and graphical I would not "worry" about the cosmetics of the form. In the following I have made k=1 (no values for $\delta$'s given). to avoid numerical problems just due to extreme scales (v precision). I have tried to "correct" the unbalanced parentheses referred to by Bob Hanlon. I may have made an error. If so, I apologize:

```
fun[δ0_Real, δ1_Real, δ2_Real, θ_,k_Real] := 
  ExpToTrig[
   1/k (Exp[-I δ0] Sin[δ0] + 
      3 Exp[I δ1] Sin[δ1 ] Cos[θ] + 
      5/2 Exp[I δ2 ] (3 (Cos[θ])^2 - 1))];
g[r_, s_, t_, u_, v_] := 
 Chop[fun[r, s, t, u, v] Conjugate[fun[r, s, t, u, v]]]
```

[image]

I hope this be a kick start to the desired result. Apologies for any misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
gc=Conjugate[g[θ]]/.Conjugate[cos_Cos]->cos
```

and `h=g*gc` and use `h` as the integrand or plotted function. One should avoid calling `Simplify` inside `Plot` or `Integrate` because this will be much slower than necessary.

Also, your integrand contains a factor `10^-30`. So it is practically zero and nothing is plotted and the integral is zero.