# BlankSequence with Plus

Tags: pattern-matching

When I execute `f[g[a, b]] /. f[g[l__]] :> f[l]` I get `f[a, b]` as expected.

When I execute `f[a + b] /. f[Plus[l__]] :> f[l]` I get `f[a + b]`. (I expect `f[a, b]` again)

Why?
(Wolfram Mathematica 12.2.0)

Comment: Interesting:  `f[Plus[a, b]] /. f[g_[l1__]] :> f[l1]`  gives: `f[a, b]`

Answer (score 11):

This happens because `Plus[l__]` evaluates to `l__` **before** the pattern is even replaced. Try instead:

```
f[a + b] /. f[HoldPattern@Plus[l__]] :> f[l]
```

Comment: you can also do `f[a + b] /. f[l_Plus]] :> f[l]`

Comment: That still evaluates to `f[a + b]`, right?