# Confusing abnormalities observed when counting a specific operator in an expression

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, operators, counting

Recently I have met with some confusing abnormalities when trying to determine if there is a specific operator (usually `Plus[]` ) in an expression by programming. The method I came up with was to use `Count[expr, Operator Function[__], levelspec]`,and the levlespec is 1 by default so it can be omitted for my purpose. And my notion was that, positive results greater than 0 indicates the existence of such operator.

The confusing abnormalities I have encountered are:

1.The results counting from the expr itself and all other known forms are in discrepancy. Previously I thought when doing `Count[]`, what MMA counts is the `FullForm` of the expr, but it turned out to be false since the counting result from `FullForm` is usually the same with other known forms but just at odds with that from the expr itself. So I was wondering what on earth form does MMA count from when doing it on the expr itself.

For instance,

```
With[{expr = 1/Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + y^2 + z^2]}, 
 Table[Count[i, 
   Plus[__]], {i, {FullForm[expr], StandardForm[expr], 
    InputForm[expr], OutputForm[expr], TraditionalForm[expr], expr}}]]
```

returns `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2}`.

```
With[{expr = x^3 + y^3 + z^3}, 
 Table[Count[i, 
   Plus[__]], {i, {FullForm[expr], StandardForm[expr], 
    InputForm[expr], OutputForm[expr], TraditionalForm[expr], expr}}]]
```

returns `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}`.

2.When there is totally no such operators in the expr, the `Count[]` can still give me a positive result greater than 0, how come? At some point, it made me feel my computer was haunted.

For example,

```
With[{expr = z r^2}, 
 Table[Count[i, 
   Plus[__]], {i, {FullForm[expr], StandardForm[expr], 
    InputForm[expr], OutputForm[expr], TraditionalForm[expr], expr}}]]
```

and

```
With[{expr = Sqrt[a/b]}, 
 Table[Count[i, 
   Plus[__]], {i, {FullForm[expr], StandardForm[expr], 
    InputForm[expr], OutputForm[expr], TraditionalForm[expr], expr}}]]
```

both return`{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2}`.But the exprs `z r^2` and `Sqrt[a/b]` do not have any `Plus[__]` at all, how can `Count[]` find 1 or 2 `Plus[__]` in them?

Any ideas about the two abnormalities found above?

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree. Your problem does not is not  the expression, but the fact that your pattern is evaluated. To prevent this enclose it in "HoldPattern"

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(241301)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/241301). Also related: [(251177)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/251177)

Comment: Thanks @DanielHuber and @Michael E2, I have realized the key issue here. I had long noticed the function `HoldPattern[]` but never bothered to learn it in detail until your suggestion. I believe this time `HoldPattern[]`  and related issues have left me a deep enough impression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Plus[__]` is getting evaluated to just `__`. You could wrap it in HoldPattern, or you could just use `_Plus` (meaning an expression with head Plus). Alternatively, since it seems you only care about the presence of something, you could use MemberQ (using a level specification of Infinity). Specifically, replace your Count expression with `MemberQ[i, _Plus, Infinity]`. As a side note, the *Form functions are intended for display purposes, and I'd be wary of using them for any sort of semantic/analytic computation.

Comment: Thanks @lericr, I have realized the key issue here. I had long noticed the function HoldPattern[] but never bothered to learn it in detail until your suggestion. I believe this time HoldPattern[] and related issues have left me a deep enough impression.

Comment: By the way, your `MemberQ[]` seems attractive, but it does not work on some simple example, like `MemberQ[a + b + c, _Plus, Infinity]` gives me `False`, I don't know why.

Comment: The expression `a+b+c` is really `Plus[a, b, c]`, in which case the Plus is the head of the expression, and MemberQ excludes the head of the expression by default when determining membership. You can change the levelspec like this: `MemberQ[a + b + c, _Plus, {0, Infinity}]`. There may be other ways that are better--I wasn't suggesting that MemberQ was the ultimate solution, just an alternate that might be worth considering.

Comment: Got it. I would have never known that it can actually designate the level specification to be 0 in MemberQ[]. Thanks for your help. Have a nice day!