# Finding real and imaginary parts

Tags: simplifying-expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract real part of a complex expression better than Re does](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/extract-real-part-of-a-complex-expression-better-than-re-does)

I have an expression and I would like to find its real and imaginary parts. As a simplification, suppose the expression is $(a+bi)^2$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}.$

Of course

```
Re[(a + b I)^2]
```

does not work, since Mathematica doesn't know that $a$ and $b$ are real. So I tried

```
Assuming[Element[{a, b}, Reals], Re[(a + b I)^2]]
```

which also fails, even if I hit it with `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`. Then I thought that perhaps `Re` was impermeable to the simplification engine, so I expanded it first:

```
FullSimplify[Assuming[Element[{a, b}, Reals], Re[Expand[(a + b I)^2]]]]
```

This gives

> Re(a^2-b^2)-2 Im(a b)

as the answer, which is closer but still maddeningly incomplete. (Either Mathematica doesn't know that the reals are closed under multiplication and addition or it doesn't know how to find the real or imaginary part of a real number.)

Is there a way I can better express my intentions to Mathematica?

Comment: Use `ComplexExpand`

Comment: @rm-rf: I get the same answer, `Re(a^2-b^2)-2 Im(a b)`.

Comment: I get `a^2 - b^2`. What exactly did you do?

Comment: @rm-rf: `FullSimplify[
 Assuming[Element[{a, b}, Reals], Re[ComplexExpand[(a + b I)^2]]]]`

Comment: Mathematica version 8.0.1.0, 64-bit for Windows.

Comment: How come your outputs have round function brackets instead of square ones?

Comment: Use `ComplexExpand[Re[(a + b I)^2]]`. You have Re and ComplexExpand in the wrong order.

Comment: uplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/extract-real-part-of-a-complex-expression-better-than-re-does/) and pretty similar to [i](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9340/complex-number-operations-telling-mathematica-variables-are-real/), [ii](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16414/how-can-i-convert-a-complex-number-ab-i-to-the-exponent-form-a-expi-phi/), [iii](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15961/a-problem-about-simplifing-conjugate) and probably others as well.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: I set my default output to `TraditionalForm`.